# PHP & MySQL Display Select Tag Multiple Values from Database

Tags: php, tags, jquery-select2

I'm trying to display a value of saved multiple select tag from database going back to form.

Currently I have this code for saving the multiple select tag in the database

```
    /**
 * @param $word
 * @return string
 */
public function explodeTags($tags){
    $str = "";
    foreach ($tags as $tag){
        $str .= $tag.",";
    }

    return substr($str, 0, -1);
}
```

My select2 Tag picker Jquery Config

```
 $(".manpowerType").select2({
        width:"100%",
        placeholder: "Select",
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true
    });
```

I'm passing the value of select tag in a function to explode it with a comma so the value saved in the database look like this `Regular Promoter,Roving Team Leader,Team Leader`

Now my problem is when i'm trying to retrieve the data the value of my select tag look like this. Instead of separating the values with a comma it is being merge as one whole tag.

[image]

The correct value must be look like this.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me the proper way to retrieve this data from database to my select tag? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `explode()`?

Comment: I think, no need to append `,`

Comment: No haven't tried it I thought that select2 can explode the comma separated directly?

Comment: can you show us how you config your select2 input?

Comment: @catcon I updated the question with my select2 config

Comment: try add `tokenSeparators: [',']` to your select2 config

Comment: It does not work